# How to extend a matplotlib axis if the ticks are labels and not numeric?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a number of charts, made with matplotlib and seaborn, that look like the example below.

- I show how certain quantities evolve over time on a lineplot
- The x-axis labels are not numbers but strings (e.g. 'Q1' or '2018 first half' etc)
- **I need to "extend" the x-axis to the right, with an empty period.** The chart must show from Q1 to Q4, but there is no data for Q4 (the Q4 column is full of nans)
- I need this because I need the charts to be side-by-side with others which do have data for Q4
- matplotlib doesn't display the column full of nans
- If the x-axis were numeric, it would be easy to extend the range of the plot; since it's not numeric, I don't know which x_range each tick corresponds to
- **I have found the solution below. It works, but** it's not elegant: I use integers for the x-axis, add 1, then set the labels back to the strings. **Is there a more elegant way?**

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import seaborn as sns

df =pd.DataFrame()
df['period'] = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']
df['a'] = [3,4,5,np.nan]
df['b'] = [4,4,6,np.nan]
df = df.set_index( 'period')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.lineplot( data = df, ax =ax[0])

df_idx = df.index

df2 = df.set_index( np.arange(1, len(df_idx) + 1 ))

sns.lineplot(data = df2, ax = ax[1])
ax[1].set_xlim(1,4)
ax[1].set_xticklabels(df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add these lines of code for `ax[0]`

```
left_buffer,right_buffer = 3,2
labels = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']

extanded_labels = ['']*left_buffer + labels + ['']*right_buffer
left_range = list(range(-left_buffer,0))
right_range = list(range(len(labels),len(labels)+right_buffer))
ticks_range = left_range + list(range(len(labels))) + right_range
aux_range = list(range(len(extanded_labels)))

ax[0].set_xticks(ticks_range)
ax[0].set_xticklabels(extanded_labels)

xticks = ax[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()
for ind in aux_range[0:left_buffer]: xticks[ind].tick1line.set_visible(False)
for ind in aux_range[len(labels)+left_buffer:len(labels)+left_buffer+right_buffer]: xticks[ind].tick1line.set_visible(False)
```

in which `left_buffer` and `right_buffer` are margins you want to add to the left and to the right, respectively. Running the code, you will get

[image: output]

Comment: Brilliant, I owe you a beer! Just one question - is there an easy way to adjust the ranges so that there is a little bit of a gap to the left and to the right? The right subplot starts immediately at the first xtick, while the left subplot doesn't

Comment: Also, what if I need to extend by one or two periods to the left? Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous You're welcome :) Of course, check out my updated post :)

Comment: Not sure if it deserves a separate question, but is there a way to tell matplotlib to not "chop off" the leftmost and rightmost data poins if they are nans?

Answer (score 0):

I may have actually found a simpler solution: I can draw a transparent line (`alpha = 0` ) by plotting x = index of the dataframe, ie with all the labels, including those for which all values are nans, and y = the average value of the dataframe, so as to be sure it's within the range:

```
sns.lineplot(x = df.index, y = np.ones(df.shape[0]) * df.mean().mean()  , ax = ax[0], alpha =0 )
```

This assumes the scale of the y a xis has not been changed manually; a better way of doing it would be to check whether it has:

```
y_centre = np.mean([ax[0].get_ylim()])
sns.lineplot(x = df.index, y = np.ones(df.shape[0]) * y_centre  , ax = ax[0], alpha =0 )
```

Drawing a transparent line forces matplotlib to extend the axes so as to show all the x values, even those for which all the other values are nans.